# Shorten array if total length of strings is longer than specified value (for loop) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to shorten a text, if it is longer than a specified number.

So `shorten_text_easy(text, 30)`, should return `"We believe. In the future"`.

The first loop is working and displaying the correct total length of the strings in the array, but the second is where the error is, but I can't seem to find the issue.

```js
var text = "We believe. In the future. The future is here. This is a test. We are testing.";

function shorten_text_easy(text, number) {
  var text_array = text.split('. ').join('.///').split('///'); // Splitting the text into an array

  var text_array_length = text_array.length;
  var total_text_array_length = 0; // Predefining value to zero; The total length of all strings in the array

  for (var i = 0; i < text_array_length; i++) { // To run while i is short than the length of the array
    total_text_array_length += text_array[i].length; // 
  }
  total_text_array_length = total_text_array_length + text_array_length - 1; // To exclude spaces which are omitted in array
  console.log(total_text_array_length); // To show in console the first value of total_array_length

  for (total_text_array_length; total_text_array_length > number; text_array.pop(-1), text_array_length--) { // Trying to remove the last item of an array if the total length of all strings in the array is larger than the number
    for (var i = 0; i < text_array_length; i++) {
      total_text_array_length += text_array[i].length;
      console.log(total_text_array_length);
    }
    total_text_array_length = total_text_array_length + text_array_length - 1;
  }
  return text_array // This should return the end text array, when the total length of all strings is lower than 'number'
};
console.log(
  shorten_text_easy(text, 30)
);
```

Comment: And the error is what?

Comment: shortenText(text, length) return text.substr(0, length);

Comment: The error is that it returns an empty text, and when it should find the new total_text_array_length, it keeps adding string lengths to the total - which makes it return an empty array

Comment: I want it to return the text with full sentences (hence why I split it into arrays). "shortenText(text, length) return text.substr(0, length);" will cut off the text in the middle of a sentence

Comment: See my second example for a fullstop addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
function shortenTextNextDot (text, length) {
    var firstDot = text.indexOf(".") + 1;
    if (length <= firstDot) {
        return text.slice(0, firstDot);
    } else {
        var textLength = text.slice(0, length);
        var restText = text.slice(length);
        var nextDot = restText.indexOf(".") + 1;
        var finalSentence = textLength + restText.slice(0, nextDot);
        
        return finalSentence;
    }
}

function shortenTextPrevDot (text, length) {
    var firstDot = text.indexOf(".") + 1;

    if (length <= firstDot) {
        return text.slice(0, firstDot);
    } else {
        var textLength = text.slice(0, length);
        var lastDot = textLength.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
        var finalSentence = textLength.slice(0, lastDot);

        return finalSentence;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing on last full stop that fits

```js
const shorten_text_easy = (text, number) => {
  let res = text.slice(0,number);
  const pos = res.lastIndexOf(".");
  return pos > 0 ? res.slice(0,pos+1) : res;
}  
var text = "We believe. In the future. The future is here. This is a test. We are testing.";

console.log(
  shorten_text_easy(text, 30)
);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's the idea yeah! Is there any way to modify this, so that the sentence cut's off at the next occurence of '.'? `So shorten_text_easy(text, 20)` will display: "We believe. In the future."?